# Clear/ empty VRAM after using torch model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, torch

I am new to torch, so forgive me if this has been asked before. I am using OpenAI's [Point-E](https://github.com/openai/point-e), and I am trying to reduce VRAM usage after the model has been ran. How can I empty VRAM after running this code block:

```
import torch
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

from point_e.diffusion.configs import DIFFUSION_CONFIGS, diffusion_from_config
from point_e.diffusion.sampler import PointCloudSampler
from point_e.models.download import load_checkpoint
from point_e.models.configs import MODEL_CONFIGS, model_from_config
from point_e.util.plotting import plot_point_cloud

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

print('creating base model...')
base_name = 'base40M-textvec'
base_model = model_from_config(MODEL_CONFIGS[base_name], device)
base_model.eval()
base_diffusion = diffusion_from_config(DIFFUSION_CONFIGS[base_name])

print('creating upsample model...')
upsampler_model = model_from_config(MODEL_CONFIGS['upsample'], device)
upsampler_model.eval()
upsampler_diffusion = diffusion_from_config(DIFFUSION_CONFIGS['upsample'])

print('downloading base checkpoint...')
base_model.load_state_dict(load_checkpoint(base_name, device))

print('downloading upsampler checkpoint...')
upsampler_model.load_state_dict(load_checkpoint('upsample', device))

sampler = PointCloudSampler(
    device=device,
    models=[base_model, upsampler_model],
    diffusions=[base_diffusion, upsampler_diffusion],
    num_points=[1024, 4096 - 1024],
    aux_channels=['R', 'G', 'B'],
    guidance_scale=[3.0, 0.0],
    model_kwargs_key_filter=('texts', ''), # Do not condition the upsampler at all
)

# Set a prompt to condition on.
prompt = 'a red motorcycle'

# Produce a sample from the model.
samples = None
for x in tqdm(sampler.sample_batch_progressive(batch_size=1, model_kwargs=dict(texts=[prompt]))):
    samples = x

pc = sampler.output_to_point_clouds(samples)[0]
fig = plot_point_cloud(pc, grid_size=3, fixed_bounds=((-0.75, -0.75, -0.75),(0.75, 0.75, 0.75)))
```

I've tried this, but both prints returned the same value:

```
print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(device))

device = None
gc.collect()

with torch.no_grad():
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(device))
```

Comment: The code in the first part appears to be in the global scope. Are the models you defined still in scope? The garbage collector won't clean up memory that still has live references.